# Check ownership of android.view.View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

Is there a way to check if a certain view (e.g. Button, etc.) belongs to an fragment? `View.getContext()` provides me with the activity, and fragments do not have their own context. However, I need some sort of workaround to find out if a button is part of a fragment and retreive the fragments name or class or whatever.

Use case: A `View.OnClickListener` provides me with the view in `onClick(View view)`. Now I can find out almost everything about this view object: Its type (e.g. button), its resource id, even its resource name from the XML file can be resolved using the activity context. However, there is no way of finding out if the view is part of a fragment or if it lies directly inside the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two approaches to this:

As a prerequisite you need to be able to iterate through the list of fragments visible on screen (i.e. candidates that this view may be a child view of). Then you can either:

1. Repeatedly call `View.getParent()` until the returned view is root view of the fragment you are checking, or you reach the top of the view hierarchy. e.g.

   ```
   boolean isViewPartOfFragment(View view, Fragment fragment) {
       View fragmentRootView = fragment.getView();
       while (view != null) {
           if (view == fragmentRootView) {
               return true;
           }
           view = (View) view.getParent();
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, for each fragment, you can call `findViewById()` or `findViewByTag()` on the root view to see if the view is part of its view hierarchy (although as these perform a tree search it will likely yield a slower approach). e.g.

   ```
   boolean isViewPartOfFragment2(View view, Fragment fragment) {
       Object tag = new Object();
       view.setTag(tag); // careful, will overwrite any existing tag!
       View foundView = fragment.getView().findViewByTag(tag);
       return (view == foundView);
   }
   ```

Although thinking about this more, the fact you are resorting to one of these methods suggests there may be a much simpler way of achieving your end goal. Whereabouts are you setting the view's `OnClickListener`? Is it possible for you to set the listener inside the fragment that owns the view and therefore be called with a reference to the fragment directly available?

Answer (score 0):

you can get its parent via this

```
yourView.getParent()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent()